# jQuery Javascript Menu Navigation add remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

When a site is `www.example.com` and loads `index.html` the navigation will not have preselected home to show. I have a function that populates the menu and another to get current page to add the class which loops and I know I can not find when the site is `www.example.com` the `index.html` page to change the class to be current.

I have tried different if statements and tried putting a default class in `li` i.e. `<li><a href='index.html' class='current'>Home</a></li>` but it would show both this and any other page I visit.

```
/*Navigation menu*/
function navMenu(){
document.writeln("<ul id='menu' class='menu'>");
document.writeln("<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>"); 
document.writeln("<li><a href='myself.html'>About</a></li>");
document.writeln("<li><a href='portfolio.html'>Work</a></li>");
document.writeln("<li><a href='news.html'>News</a></li>");
document.writeln("<li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li></ul>");   
}


function setActive() {
/*current page function*/
 $('#menu a').each(function(index) {
    if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
        $(this).addClass("current");
});}
```

This works fine but like I mentioned I don't understand how to integrate a add or finding if there was a default class at the start when the URL would be `www.example.com` I would add the current class to `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

If you load `index.html` when you call `/,` just change the href of the homepage to `/` instead of `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the href on the a tags you're going to want to check against the `pathname`

```
function setActive() {
/*current page function*/
 $('#menu a').each(function(index) {
    if(this.href.trim() == window.location.pathname)
        $(this).addClass("current");
});}
```

Comment: thanks the location.pathname seemed to not work for when i tried to compare href to it. I am using the method above. cheers though